# Conditional Probability in a judge/suspect problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

The verdict given by a judge is 90% reliable when a suspect is guilty and 99% reliable when the suspect is innocent. **If the suspect is selected from a group of people of whom 5% have ever committed a crime and the judge finds him guilty**, what is the probability that the suspect is innocent?

My job:
Let $I$ the event "the suspect is innocent". Then

$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(I)&=&P(I|\mbox{Judge is reliable})P(\mbox{Judge is reliable})\\
&&+P(I|\mbox{Judge is not reliable})P(\mbox{Judge is not reliable})\\
\end{eqnarray*}$

On the other hand, I know $P(\mbox{Judge is reliable}|I^c)=0.9$ and $P(\mbox{Judge is reliable}|I)=0.99$. Now, I don't know how to use the bold hypothesis. I don't know how to proced.

Comment: Use Bayes' theorem

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote "ever". Does that imply that the judge's verdict is counted as correct if they find someone guilty who has **ever** committed a crime, not necessarily the one they were charged with (and innocent only if they've **never** committed **any** crime)? Otherwise, the "ever" creates a disconnect between the various data given.

Comment: Define terms of the sort $P[suspect~found~innocent|suspect~IS~innocent]$, $P[suspect~found~guilty|suspect~is~innocent]$, $P[suspect~found~guilty|suspect~IS~guilty]$ and $P[suspect~found~guilty|suspect~is~innocent]$ and work from Bayes rule.

Comment: Yes. Normally i don't ask for help for this kind of exercises, but i'm really confused in this one.Thanks

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, what is the diference between normal and capital letter?

Comment: One convention is to use $P[...]$ to denote the probability of an *event*, and lowercase $p(...)$ to denote a probability *density*.  Don't get hung up on this notational matter.  Just set up everything in terms of Bayes rule and you'll be fine.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork i mean: in your comment, you write $P[...|... IS...]$ and the same but with $P[...|... is...]$.

Comment: That is merely a typographic method for stressing a point... it has no mathematical significance.

Comment: Of course, one issue here is that we are only told that the suspect come from a group where $5\%$ have ever committed *a* crime; not necessarily *this* crime

Answer (score 1):

You want the *conditional* probability that the Suspect is Innocent *given* the Judge found him Guilty.

The suspect will be *found* Guilty if either: Is Innocent and Judge not reliable, or Is not Innocent and the Judge is reliable.

$$\mathsf P(I\mid G)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(I\cap G)}{\mathsf P(G)}=\dfrac{\mathsf P(I\cap J^\complement)}{\mathsf P(I\cap J^\complement)+\mathsf P(I^\complement\cap J)}$$

Comment: Of course, one issue here is that we are only told that the suspect come from a group where $5\%$ have ever committed *a* crime; not necessarily *this* crime.

Answer (score 0):

This is an application of Bayes' theorem!

$P(I) = P(I\mid\text{Guilty})P(\text{Guilty})$

and we know that $P(\text{Guilty})=0.05$.

Now, using Bayes' theorem,

\begin{equation}
P(I\mid\text{Guilty}) = P(\text{Guilty}\mid I) \frac{P(I)}{P(\text{Guilty})}
\end{equation}

In our population, the probability of innocent is $0.95$ and the probability of guilty is $0.05$;  therefore $P(I)/P(\text{Guilty})=0.95/0.05$.  And $P(\text{Guilty}\mid I)=0.01$.  So now we can use Bayes' theorem to find $P(I\mid\text{Guilty})$, and we can plug that in our first equation to get the answer.

Comment: There is a distinction between being guilty and being *found* guilty.  We are told $5\%$ of the population have committed a crime, not that the judge will find $5\%$ of them guilty.